# angularjs: (bootstrap) popover directive. How to close it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a pattern related question. I build a directive to "load" content into a bootstrap popover.

HTML:

```
<span data-ng-show="user.provider === 'local'" class="label label-warning" data-popover="" data-placement="bottom" data-content-selector="#passwordchangeform">change password</span>
<div id="passwordchangeform" style="display:none;">
    <h3>Change password</h3>
    <h4>(Not finished yet!)</h4>
    <form>
        Old password:
        <input type="text" ng-model="username" name="text"/><br/>
        New password:
        <input type="text" ng-model="password1" name="text"/><br/>
        New password again:
        <input type="text" ng-model="password2" name="text"/><br/>
        <input type="button" data-ng-click="login()" value="login"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('popover', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            var content;

            if (attrs.content) {
                content = attrs.content;
            } else {
                content = $compile("<div>" + $(attrs.contentSelector).html() + "</div>")(scope);
            }

            $(el).popover({
                trigger: 'click',
                html: true,
                content: content,
                placement: attrs.placement
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In my controller, I implemented the function login()
Let's say in the controller login() function I get a success response to a HTTP/POST
What would be the best-practice then on actually closing the popover?? I can think of "dirty hacks" to force the closure, but I guess it could be done in a more appropriate way...

The "problem" I may have maybe related to the fact I'm using $compile in the directive to tie the content to the scope of the controller so I'm unable to close it from the link function.

Thanks,

Sander

Comment: You can try to `$broadcast` an event when getting a success response and then handle that event in your `link` function and `close` the popover.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought of as well to just get it working... or a watcher on a var that is set on success, but it feels a bit "dodgy", don't you think?

Comment: Yes, in some sense, but IMO it would be the best solution. Another one can be an additional `directive(property)` called `close`, which by setting `true` will `close` the popover. And the changes you will handle using `$watch` as you said. **BUT** this code also must be placed in you `link` function.

Comment: So I think the `$broadcast` is the way to go.

Comment: Another solution I can think of is passing the login function to the attrs and actually call it from the directive. It means rewriting the login function to use a callback, which is doable of course ..... but it all just feels like trickery and not very "clean" for sure...Im just afraid I'm overlooking some easy silver bullet ;-)

Comment: I implemented it now using your suggested broadcast. However, a potentially unwanted side-effect is that when you have multiple popovers on a page, they would all get the event and they would all close. This I can live with for the moment, so I will continue. To circumvent this you would still have to add another directive property with the event name OR pass the element/id somehow and loop through all popovers and close the single one.....

Comment: You can pass additional arguments through broadcast, for example popover's ID, without creating a new directive. Please refer here for details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast

Comment: Yes I know. The thing is however that the controller is unaware of the popover, including it's ID/selector.... so I would have to manually put the selectorname in the controller OR pass the $event to the login function... all doable, don't get me wrong, I really appreciate you answer/the discussion.. but you have to agree this is  all a bit ugly....

Comment: I think the AngularJS gives a lot of flexibility and that is the reason why you should write lots of stuff for that small thing. But, in general, its all a bit ugly and I agree with you.